# Determine Current Controller in Use for Kohana

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller, kohana

What is the best way to determine which Controller class a Kohana application is presently using?

Examples:

- `http://sitesite.com/` - `_defaultControllerName_`
- `http://somesite.com/frontpage/articles` - "frontpage"
- `http://somesite.com/contact/` - "contact"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***The following applies to Kohana 2 instances...***

You can do this by using the Router library. By default, this library is located in `/system/libraries/Router.php` - go ahead and copy it into `/application/libraries` as is the standard practice for all libraries being used.

Now, from within your application you can get the controller value from the static Router class:

```
print Router::$controller; // outputs current Controller
```

[Documentation](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/routing?s%5B%5D=router#controller)

Comment: Just found this out for myself - thought I'd share for anybody coming across it in the future.

Answer (score 5):

**For Kohana 3.x**, you need to get the current controller from the Request object:

```
echo Request::$current->controller();
```